# Django - URLS not rendering view in root homepage

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to render data from my model named `user_profile` and for some reason when I try to render the `create_view_two` view to the root of my project which is called `home.html`, the page will not render the view.

However if I have the `create_view_two` view pointing to a different page it works.

Example below:

## user_profile/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("test/", create_view_two, name='home'),
]
```

## user_profile/views.py

```
   return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

I would like to point this view to the root of my project which is `localhost:8000` and not something different. How can I do that?

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Cheers

## user_profile/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser


def create_view_two(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all()
    user = request.user

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

## user_profile/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from .views import create_view, create_view_two

urlpatterns = [
    path('myaccount/', create_view, name='myaccount'),
    path('', create_view_two, name='home'),
]
```

## master_application/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('user_profile.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),    
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## myapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from .views import HomePageView, MyAccountView, AboutPageView, PrivacyPageView, ContactPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),    
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('privacy/', PrivacyPageView.as_view(), name='privacy'),
    path('contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('myaccount/', MyAccountView.as_view(), name='myaccount'),
]
```

## home.html

```
 {% for profile_two in user_profile%} 
<p>{{ profile_two.rank }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: _I would like to point this view to the root of my app and not something different._ what do you mean? You want that view to render at `localhost:8000/` in development?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf that is correct. I'm new to Django so I'm trying to wrap my head around all this. How do i that with my current code?

Comment: Try hardcoded data in home.html, it may be you context is not passing the data.

Comment: @spidey677, what is the name of your Django project?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf it's called `gstation`

Comment: @spidey6777, `main.urls` is the file in which you have the urls in your Django project? Btw, do you have clear the difference between a Django project and a Django app?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Yes it is. No but I just looked it up and now i know :)

Comment: @spidey677, I don't get the point of the file `main.urls`, where are you putting that, and why doesn't it have a .py extension?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I'm sorry. I put this together pretty quickly and I just corrected it to `master_application/urls.py`. This is how I was taught to put the foundations of a django project together. `master_application/urls.py` would load the urls at the root for the whole Django project to make it easier for development.

Comment: @spidey677, I don't understand why you have a `views.py` in your Django project directory.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I'm trying to render data from my model named `user_profile` into the html so I included `views.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the app `user_profile`, in which you have claimed is the view `create_view_two`, use the following:

#### user_profile/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from . import views

app_name = "user_profile"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.create_view_two, name="home"),
]
```

Then in `urls.py` that is inside your project's directory use something like this:

#### myapp/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("user_profile.urls")),
]
```

Then, you will have the `create_view_two` rendered at `localhost:8000/`.

Comment: Since I'm trying to render data from my model named `user_profile`, do I need to put that in`app_name = "app_name"`?

Comment: if your app is named `user_profile`, you have to use `user_profile` instead, and you have to use `user_profile.urls` in `myapp/urls.py`

Comment: @spidey677, I just updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: I debugged further and found that moving `path('', include('user_profile.urls')),` to the first row solved the issue. Thank you my friend!

Comment: @spidey677, you're welcome. I'm glad the problem was solved.